# Redirect to chrome webstore from chrome packaged apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

How to redirect to chrome webstore from chrome packaged app if there is an update available for our app ?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#event-onUpdateAvailable

Comment: Updates happen automatically.